# Android MainActivity calls another Activities, after pressing back key, blank screen shows

Tags: android, layout, android-activity, android-layout

my main.xml file is just dummy.  I want to start different activites based on the condition.  If the password is found in shared pref file, the login activity should be launched, and if password is not found, the configuration activity should be launched.  it is working fine but when I press the back key from keypad, the main activity is shown (I mean the blank screen because there is nothing)  How can I avoid this?

```
 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        prefs = getSharedPreferences(preffilename, MODE_PRIVATE);
        final String password = prefs.getString("password",null);

        if(password == null)
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Configuration.class);
            startActivity(i);
        } 
        else
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `finish()` from your main activity after calling `startActivity()`, this will remove main activity from stack.

Answer (score 0):

What is your expectation when you pressed the back button? You might want to put those code in onResume() so it always get called when the main activity is brought back from the stack.